# Handling master / detail tables in Forms (automatically appending data to detail table if unique)

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007

I'm working on access and just finished my database scheme (access backend and frontend). Now I have a rather simple question, but I can't get my head around it. I have a few master tables and a lot of detail tables (1:n). For simplification I just use the following scheme:

Articles (Auto-ID, Type_ID(long integer), Description(text));
Types(Auto-ID, Type(text))

One article has one type, one type can be used in many articles. Plain and simple.

I created the corresponding relationship (w/o referential integrity) and a formular where you can enter an article (Description, Type). When I now enter a 'type' that is already existing in the types-table, access just enters the type again into the table with a new ID instead of using the existing ID (combinationfield, recordsource is "select ID and Type from Types"). Even if I choose an existing value a new ID gets created.

In my head access would automatically take care of this, so I guess I just can't see what I messed up. 
Well ... is this the way it is supposed to go? Did I just miss something? Or do I have to take care of that via VBA (which won't be a problem but a lot of work)? I really appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I take it your form is based on a query that has an inner join on Articles and Types.  If instead you make your form based solely on Articles. Then add a combo box to the form that is bound to Type_ID in the Articles table. The row source of the combo box will be the Types table.  (The wizard should step you through the setup)

Comment: This helped a lot! For a new entry I would have to use the not_in_list event, right? And is there any downside to this approach? I tried using a recourdsource with a left join query which worked smoothly, so I guess there won't be any more problems.

Comment: I don't think you need the outer join unless you want to display both the TypeId and TypeDesc. Normally you would only display the description.  in the combo box use two columns, the first column is the bound column (id) with a width of 0. the second column is the description with an appropriate width.

Comment: Yes of course, the outer join reference is not applicable for my example and was not supposed to be. Like I stated before, the example is a huge simplification and in my data model I am going to need a few outer joins. I just wanted to say I tried that too, so every required scenario can be accomplished.